# WSO2 ESB cannot obtain url parameters that contains comma

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB 490 I have wrote the simple API:

```html
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="paramsTest" context="/params">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/p?try={params_list}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="params_list" expression="get-property('uri.var.params_list')"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="The input params : " expression="get-property('params_list')"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"res_body":"$1"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('params_list')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

It work fine when access by URL:

```html
http://localhost:8290/params/p?try=one
```

and response {"res_body":"one"}

But when access by this URL :

```html
http://localhost:8290/params/p?try=one,two
```

It response nothing, and it seems ESB didn't process the request because of parameters "try=one,two" separate by comma.

How can make ESB process this URL?(parameters separate by comma)

Comment: Can you try as one%2Ctwo

Comment: Thanks very much, it can work. Does it mean we should advise user encode their URL every call?

Comment: yes. I think you need to encode the comma with %2c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK you need to encode the comma with %2C when using with url params.
e.g.

```
http://localhost:8290/params/p?try=one%2Ctwo
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get the parameter list via a property you will get %2C encoded values with parameters. Have a look at the working example mentioned below.

```
 <resource methods="POST" uri-template="?sessionId={id}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="sessionId" expression="$url:sessionId"/>
```

Extract parameters one by one as mentioned above.